# jQuery hasClass returns true but removeClass doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This has been fixed. It was poor programming. I was calling the function twice. so it was removing the class but when the function ran the second time it was readding the class. Sorry for my poor programming and thank you all for trying to help. I love stackoverflow because of all the helpful people!

Alright so I have been trying to figure out something but it just might be my cold that is stopping me from solving it. What I am doing is when the user selects something it adds a class. but than if they select it again I want to remove the class. So I checked to see if the element hasClass which returns true but than when I do removeClass it does nothing...

Modified the JS to look like this. To show that I can see that the Selectedindex and index do match and that the removeClass for "option-select" is being skipped/ignored for some reason. I can change it to say removeClass("option") and it works just fine but I can not removeClass("option-selected")

```
$(obj.find('.option')).each(function(Selectedindex) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('option-selected') && Selectedindex == index) {
        $(this).removeClass('option-selected');
        console.log(Selectedindex+" == "+index);
    }
});
```

index is passed to the function when the element is selected.

here is some of the HTML

```
<div id="MultipleSelect-HTML" class="dropdown container" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;">
    <ul class="options" style="width: 100%; display: block; position: relative;">
        <li>
            <a class="option option-selected"> 
                <input class="option-value" type="hidden" value="0"> 
                <img class="option-image" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inside/PNG/032x032/icontexto-inside-facebook.png"> 
                <label class="option-text" style="cursor:pointer;">Facebook</label> 
                <small class="option-description desc">Check out my Facebook page!</small>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="option option-selected"> 
                <input class="option-value" type="hidden" value="1"> 
                <img class="option-image" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inside/PNG/032x032/icontexto-inside-twitter.png"> 
                <label class="option-text" style="cursor:pointer;">Twitter</label> 
                <small class="option-description desc">Check out my Twitter page!</small>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="option"> 
                <input class="option-value" type="hidden" value="2"> 
                <img class="option-image" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inside/PNG/032x032/icontexto-inside-linkedin.png"> 
                <label class="option-text" style="cursor:pointer;">LinkedIn</label> 
                <small class="option-description desc">Check out my LinkedIn page!</small>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="option"> <input class="option-value" type="hidden" value="3"> 
                <img class="option-image" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inside/PNG/032x032/icontexto-inside-flickr.png"> 
                <label class="option-text" style="cursor:pointer;">Flickr</label> 
                <small class="option-description desc">I don't have a flicker Page :(</small>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please keep in mind that all of this information is dynamically generated using javascript

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Comment: Can you post your HTML. Also, you are checking for `option-selected` and removing `dd-option-selected` - is that correct?

Comment: The class you are checking for and the class you are removing are different.

Comment: Yeah, fixed that thanks... but it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: What is `index`? You are passing `SelectedIndex` into the callback.

Comment: i have a function called toggleStat(obj, index) when the function is called it is passed both the current list along with the index of the selected element. That part works just fine. I get the right index and the right element, but I can't seem to remove the class from the element or any element, thought If i do 

obj.find('.option').removeClass('option-selected');

This works but this removes everything

Comment: what about `$(this).find('.option-selected').eq(index).removeClass('option-selected')`?

Comment: That was my first attempt before doing the foreach loop.

Comment: Something interesting. I can remove the class "option" but not the class "option-selected" seems to work exactly as you would expect!

Comment: Try something like this could be a work around, $(this).attr('class', $(this).attr('class').replace('option-selected',''))

Comment: That didn't work, but it made me think. I started looking though my code and realized the problem was I was calling the select twice, so when I selected somehting it removed the class but than re-ran the function reselect the element. Once I fixed that code it seems to work perfectly! Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 2):

You are doing hasClass for `option-selected` but trying to removeClass `dd-option-selected`

Assuming it is `dd-option-selected`, Change like below,

```
$(obj.find('.option')).each(function(Selectedindex) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('dd-option-selected') && Selectedindex == index)
        $(this).removeClass('dd-option-selected');
});
```

> Yeah, fixed that thanks... but it still doesn't work. Any other ideas? – Robert E. McIntosh
>
> If this has dd-option-selected and it is not removing the class then the Selectedindex is not equal to index – Vega

Comment: Yeah, fixed that thanks... but it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: If `this` has `dd-option-selected` and it is not removing the class then the `Selectedindex` is not equal to `index`

Comment: That is what I thought too, so I added "console.log(Selectedindex+" == "+index) and I do get stuff like "1 == 1" so it is finding the element. I can even do "$(this).parent().html()" and see the class itself.

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh Post the relevant HTML that you are seeing as well.

Comment: Added the HTML, it is dynamically generated using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking by `hasClass option-selected` but `removing dd-option-selected`, `you should check dd-option-selected`.

You condition would be.

```
if ($(this).hasClass('dd-option-selected') && Selectedindex == index)
        $(this).removeClass('dd-option-selected');
```

If you are not sure about the class name and class name does not matter then you can use removeAttr to remove class

```
$(this).removeAttr('class');
```

Comment: Yeah, fixed that thanks... but it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you want to remove class irrespective of name then you can use $(this).removeAttr('class');

Comment: I cant remove the entire class just one of the classes there can be a few.

Comment: Check if your statement $(this).removeClass('dd-option-selected'); is getting executed.

Comment: I know it is getting in the if statement and I can remove the class "option" not the "option-selected" though... it actually kinda getting annoying now... haha